# Proof of definition of invertible matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A \in \Bbb R^{n \times n}$. Then $A$ is invertable if and only if a Matrix $B \in \Bbb R^{n \times n}$ exist such that $AB=E$.

This seems like *the* definition of an invertible matrix but how do you prove the definition? As a physics student I don't do many proofs so it would be nice if someone could give me hint.

Comment: You cannot prove definitions. Do you rather want to show that $AB=E$ implies that $BA=E$ as well?

Comment: That's why it is not exactly the definition of an inventive matrix...

Comment: Then pray tell what is *the* definition of invertible matrix?

Comment: You also need to verify that $BA=E$

Comment: In linear algebra, an $n \times n$ square matrix $A$ is called invertible if there exists an $n \times n$ square matrix $B$ such that: $$AB=BA=I$$

@HagenvonEitzen I don't even know what I want to show.

Comment: @Jean-PierreMerx So the definition in my opening post is incomplete? Then how can I prove that statement is true?

Comment: Yes it is incomplete. SuH  gave the precise one in his comment.

Comment: @Jean-PierreMerx SuH is me ;). This is exactly what confuses me. How can I prove an incomplete definitiont? Doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: You need to show that the existence of $B$ with $AB=I$ implies that $BA=I$. My approach would be: $AB=I\Rightarrow det(A)\neq 0 \Rightarrow A$ is invertible.

Comment: This may be relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/3860/27978.

Comment: @copper.hat This combined with Taylor's hint is very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know why this was put on hold as unclear, I know exactly what it's asking.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $AB=I \implies B(AB)=B \implies (BA-I)B=0$